# Check for item and attack

Tags: bukkit

How would i check for a item and then allow  a player to do something? ok being more specific one player join i have given a player item but what i want to do is; if a player attacks a player he can only do it with the specific item in his hand, a diamond sword if he doesn't then it cancels all damage so that the attacker can not attack the victim unless he has only a diamond sword in his hand? How would i write cancelling player vs player or enabling player vs player if the attacker targets a player?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`EntityDamageByEntityEvent`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageByEntityEvent.html).

Check for a `Player` attacker on [`EntityDamageByEntityEvent.getDamager()`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageByEntityEvent.html#getDamager()), then use [`Player.getItemInHand()`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/HumanEntity.html#getItemInHand()) to verify if he's holding the needed `ItemStack`.

```
@EventHandler
public void onNormal(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) { 
    Entity attacker = event.getDamager();
    if (attacker.getType() == EntityType.PLAYER) {
        Player player = (Player)attacker;
        if (player.getItemInHand().getType() != Material.DIAMOND_SWORD) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```